# Convert SQL to Django orm with Inner Join

Tags: python, sql, django, postgresql, django-models

I'm trying to pass this SQL query to django ORM, but I have a problem with the inner join, could you please help me, thank you

I tried using a query within another query, but I have no way to compare an annotate of a GT filter

```py
Model.objects.filter( 
    status=Model.FAILED,
).filter(
    created__gt=Model.objects.filter(
        status=Model.APPROVED,
        is_active=True,
    ).annotate(
        approved_created=F('created')
    ).values_list('approved_created')
).select_related('invoice').values_list('pk')
```

This is the SQL that I want to convert

```sql
SELECT * FROM model IA1
INNER JOIN model IA2 ON IA1.invoice_id=IA2.invoice_id
WHERE IA1.status = 'FAILED'
AND IA2.status = 'APPROVED'
AND IA2.is_active = True
AND IA1.created > IA2.created;
```

Model definition

```py
class Model(models.Model):

    APPROVED = 'APPROVED'
    FAILED = 'FAILED'
    IN_PROCESS = 'IN_PROCESS'
    PENDING = 'PENDING'

    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        (APPROVED, APPROVED),
        (FAILED, FAILED),
        (IN_PROCESS, IN_PROCESS),
        (PENDING, PENDING)
    )

    status = models.CharField(
        max_length=20,
        choices=STATUS_CHOICES,
        blank=False,
        null=False,
        default=PENDING
    )

    invoice = models.ForeignKey(
        Invoice,
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        blank=False,
        related_name='assignments'
    )
```

Comment: Please include the relevant parts of the two models

Comment: If I understand it correctly, you are looking for `model`s where there was first an `APPROVED`, but now a `FAILED`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem yes exactly, but where the date of the ruling is greater than one approved

Comment: @Sayse ok, I add the definition of the model, thx

Comment: the problem is that I don't understand how to perform the inner join itself